# Remove this redundant jump in Sonarqube

Tags: c#, exception, foreach, sonarqube, continue

I have a method in which there is a for loop. The loop looks something similar as below.

```
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(somePath);
FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles();
foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
{
   try
   {
      DoSomething(file.Name);
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      continue;
   }
}
```

What I'm doing is , getting all files from a directory, run the loop all the files, get the file Name and do something. Now what I want is even if `DoSomething` method raises an exception, I want the loop to continue and do not break in between. So for that I have written `continue` in catch block.

I'm running Sonarqube to check the code quality. It is showing the message "`Remove this redundant jump.`" . I want to know how can I remove this Code smell and still achieve what I want.

Comment: `continue` isn't required

Comment: Consider what `continue;` is doing. It means 'go to the next iteration'. Now, what if you removed it? Well, nothing will happen (since you swallowed the exception) which means 'go to the next iteration'. So it is pointless. Now, if you did something **after** (not inside) the `try catch` block then Sonarqube would stop flagging it (since it would make a difference whether the `continue` was there or not).

Comment: @mjwills, thanks for your explanation.

Comment: Also, carefully consider whether `Exception` is correct here. Say, for instance, that whilst compiling the internals of `DoSomething`, the CLR throws a [`TypeLoadException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.typeloadexception(v=vs.110).aspx). This means a) there's no point in continuing into the next loop and b) you have no idea that this is happening. Try to pinpoint *specific* exceptions that you wish to suppress (but may still, at the least, want to *log* at a high enough logging level) and let others out so that they're *visible*.

Comment: `IOException` or something even more derived would probably be what you should have here. But even that may suppress some exceptions that aren't recoverable by "ignore the error" error handling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `continue` statement as the last statement in a loop is redundant. You could do this:

```
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(somePath);
FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles();
foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
{
    try
    {
        DoSomething(file.Name);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

This code works exactly the same as yours.